# Facebook public album

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, photos

I'm trying to develop an app with C# on the desktop in which one user is searching a person by email or name. It will then list users with user's information and public albums or picture. Then the program's user will look to photos if can find right searching person will add friend.

My problem is that I can't list and show public albums. I tried with FQL and graph API, but both returned null data. The code I wrote for this:

```
ArrayList  pictureLink;
public void userPhotos(string userID)
        {
            var fb2 = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

//result1 and result2 aren't using in code only for looking for with breakpoint
            dynamic result1 = fb2.Get("fql", new { q = "SELECT aid,cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner=" + kisiID });
            dynamic result2 = fb2.Get("fql", new { q = "SELECT pid,aid FROM photo WHERE owner=" + kisiID });

            ArrayList imageSize; //for gettig highest pixell of picture
            pictureLink = new ArrayList();
            var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

            //dynamic albums = fb.Get("me/albums"); // THİS code is rigth runnig
        dynamic albums = fb.Get(userID + "/albums");

            foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
            {
                //Get the Pictures inside the album this gives JASON objects list that has photo attributes 
                // described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
                dynamic albumsPhotos = fb.Get(albumInfo.id + "/photos");
                foreach (dynamic rs in albumsPhotos.data)
                {
                    imageSize= new ArrayList();
                    foreach (dynamic rsa in rs.images)
                    {
                        imageSize.Add(rsa.height);
                    }
                    int highestImage = Convert.ToInt32(imageSize[0]);
                    foreach (dynamic rsa in rs.images)
                    {
                        if (rsa.height == highestImage )
                        {
                            string link= rsa.source;
                            pictureLink.Add(link);
                        }
                    }
                }  
        }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To read an Album you need:
>
> - Any valid access token if it is public and belongs to a Page
> - The user_photos permission if it belongs to a User
> - The friend_photos permission if it belongs to a User's friend

*Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/*

What you need would be the following statement, which is *not* in the list.

> - Any valid access token if it is public and belongs to a User

It means that the API simply won't let you access to public albums. It's the same with [events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13963873/1515819).