# Public event of a private person cannot be accessed with user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I fetch events of some pages. I used app access token, but switched to user access token (of my own facebook account) due to alcohol and other restrictions. Now I can access those events.

**But I cannot access them when they're organized by a private person**, not a fanpage. Those events are public and when I use Facebook I can see them without any problem. But when I use my access token, no events are returned (not in graph api explorer, not in php sdk). **Why is that? Do I need some permission or is there some other restriction?**

To reproduce:

1. Choose a person who organises public events (but is not a Page) - use your account to see those events. E.g. https://www.facebook.com/alexandra.pajewska (she created e.g. this event http://graph.facebook.com/452665288126076 - I can see its details when using my access token).
2. Run graph api explorer and use your access token to fetch those events e.g. 1544945688/events

You should see this:

```
{
 "data": [
 ]
 }
```

---

EDIT: Probably not related to permissions. I enabled all of them in graph api explorer, but still got the same result.

Comment: I don't see any events on that user's events page, are you sure they have any events that they're marked as attending? https://www.facebook.com/alexandra.pajewska/events

Comment: Yes, I can see them with my facebook account. There are like 20 upcoming events. Maybe they're otherwise restricted, but I can give you another example. That person is not attending them, she organize them afaik

Comment: @Igy I discovered, that I cannot access any of the "connections" of a user unless it's my friend and I specify e.g. friend_events permission. But I don't think it's correct behaviour, because I can see those events, so why my user access token wouldn't suffice to see them?

Comment: What's on facebook.com and what's in the API are not necessarily the same; i definitely don't see any events on that person's timeline, if that person were using your app or a friend of a person using your app you should be able to see a list of events they're marked as attending at /USER/events with the friends_events and user_events permissions

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get the "not necessarily the same" part. It should be clear what I can see with a specific access token and what I cannot. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: The question is, why do YOU see her events on her timeline? Because we don't. Can you check again? Could you find any link you can have with her? Friend of friends?

Comment: Yes, it appears I have one common friend with her. I'll try to find someone with no connections and check how it would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) says it all:

> To read `the /events` connection of a User, you need:
>
> - the `user_events` permission for the current user
> - the `friends_events` permission for a friend of the current user

You need one permission to read the events of the **current user** and another for the **friends**. It definitely means that we are exclusively allowed to access the events of the app's user and its friends and that **we are not allowed to get a random user's events**.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I think that on Facebook you can see public events of users that you don't have any connection to. It appeared that I have one common friend, so my example may not be perfect, but I'm pretty sure, that I'd be able to find a better example (and I'll try). If I'm right, there would be no reason to restrict access to those events with Graph API (assuming those events are public)

Comment: And still, even if I don't find any example, there is discrepancy between Facebook and Graph API access - I can see her events, but not access them with GA. I don't get the reason for that

Comment: You have to do with what you have, but you can still hope for improvements!